# What does "self" argument in python mean?

Tags: python

[image]

What is the `self` parameter? Because I looked at the documentation and it only mentions `x` and `y` as parameters.

Comment: You'll want to do some reading into methods. All methods like that have a first implicit parameter `self` that's the instance. You may want to take a step back and focus on learning deeper before going into graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the declaration of any method of a class has the parameter `self`, which is **a reference to the current instance** of the class. That's what allows you to access the variables and methods in this scope.

More info [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/).

Comment: So do I have to explicitly put "self" as the first parameter when declaring or calling?

Comment: When declaring a method inside a class yes, when calling it no (it's implicit).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I found a good read for anyone else having trouble understanding:

https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-self-in-python-a3704319e5f0